# Directx11 and Tessellation

Tags: directx-11, mesh, tessellation

I am trying to create a mesh which contains more than 1 triangle that I can then tessellate. One triangle works fine but when trying to create another triangle in my mesh I get strange behaviour.

This is my vertex list.

```
vertices[0].position = XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f); // Top.
vertices[0].texture = XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 1.0f);
vertices[0].normal = XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);

vertices[1].position = XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // Bottom left.
vertices[1].texture = XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 0.0f);
vertices[1].normal = XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);

vertices[2].position = XMFLOAT3(2.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // Bottom right.
vertices[2].texture = XMFLOAT2(1.0f, 0.0f);
vertices[2].normal = XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);

vertices[3].position = XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f); // Top.
vertices[3].texture = XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 1.0f);
vertices[3].normal = XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
```

I've taken screen shots to show the behavior.
Pic 1 is taken when the camera is at (0, 0, -10). Pic 2 is when the camera is at (0, 0, 10). Pic 3 is taken at (0, 0, -10) after I changed vertices[3] to

```
vertices[3].position = XMFLOAT3(0.0f, -2.0f, 0.0f);
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1ZdQ.jpg

There are 6 values in my index array and my topology is D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_3_CONTROL_POINT_PATCHLIST.

If anyone could help I would greatly appreciate it, I'm really confused right now!

Comment: Have you looked at the [SimpleBezier](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples) sample?